# Need to delete Account during modification

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, process-builder

I need to delete accounts if not activity since 10 days using process builder

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to create a Batch class which runs daily on all the Accounts. Check if `LastModifiedDate` > 10 days and if yes, just add them to a list and delete them. So the answer is a Daily Running Batch class.

**Edit**: Added before the question said it needs to be using process builder

Comment: Is this possible to write a query                                   select id,lastmodifieddate from accountwhere lastmodifieddate >10

Comment: Yes, try this query - `Select id,LastModifiedDate from Account WHERE LastModifiedDate > LAST_N_DAYS:10`

Answer (score 2):

### For existing accounts

You could write a simple code, and execute it in `Open Execute Anonymous Window` in the developer console.

- First SOQL the list of accounts

  `Account[] accounts = [Select id,LastModifiedDate from Account WHERE LastModifiedDate > LAST_N_DAYS:10]; 
  delete accounts;`

### For new accounts

You can achieve the task by creating a combination of "Process builder" and "Visual Workflow (Flows)".

1. Create process builder on account (process builder used for time-based actions)

   - create time-based action, where you would enter `LastModifiedDate` criteria to be 10 days.
2. Create a flow  (used to delete the record )

Go through the following articles for more information on the above

- [How to delete record using flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_records_delete.htm)
- [Deleting lead using process builder and flow](http://exploiteddevorgs.com/gettingstarted/web-to-anything-part-2-deleting-the-lead-using-process-builder-and-flow/).

**P.S.** Remember you will have time "Scheduled Actions" in process builder only when

- On the object node, the process is set to **Start the process only when a record is created.** All criteria will then have the Scheduled Actions option available.
- On the object node, the process is set to **Start the process when a
  record is created or edited**, AND on the criteria node, the checkbox
  **Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are
  made to the record?** is checked. Only criteria on which this is
  checked will have the Scheduled Actions option available.